# How can I get a textbox text to be public C# forms

Tags: c#, textbox, public

For some reason when I put the int size and the board array int the public class it gives me 2 errors:
the first one is:

> a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.textBox1'

and the second one:

> a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.size'

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int size = int.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
        Button[,] board = new Button[size,size];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            random code that needs the board array
        }
        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           other random code that need the board array
        }
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the text box's text as soon as the form is initialised? The user doesn't even get a chance to enter anything into the text box!

Comment: when i put it somewhere else this error still happens
"a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.size'"

Answer (score 3):

Textbox1.Text is not initialized when Form1 is creating, so just put this in your Form Load event :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        int size = 0;
        Button[,] board;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // random code that needs the board array
        }
        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // other random code that need the board array
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text))
           {
            size = int.Parse(Textbox1.Text);
            board = new Button[size, size];
           }
        }

}
```

Comment: when i put it there this error still happens "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.size'

Comment: It's not that there is a pop up error there is just a red line under the 2 "size" in the third line

Comment: 4rth line including the parentheses

Comment: @NatiReitblat What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you were initially attempting to initialise your size value before the text box had even been created.
As you are reliant on user input to give you TextBox1.Text, I would suggest that you perform your Button[,] array initialization on your TextBox1 text entry event, even if you specify a default value for instance creation e.g. board = new Button(1,1) in the form constructor;

Comment: nvm i figured it out tnx